# Where does RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} refer to?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, rewrite, 301-redirect, host

I keep seeing website redirection have something like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
```

But where does the HTTP_HOST refer to? Is it referring to the configuration in some files or the CNAME or others?
Any idea??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` comes directly from the `Host:` header ([RFC 7230, 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4)) in the HTTP request. From [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html):

> The following variables provide the values of the named HTTP request
> headers.
>
> ```
> HTTP_ACCEPT
> HTTP_COOKIE
> HTTP_FORWARDED
> HTTP_HOST
> HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION
> HTTP_REFERER
> HTTP_USER_AGENT
> ```

That could be different e.g. from the `%{SERVER_NAME}`, the hostname specified in the `ServerName` directive of the current virtualhost; `%{HTTP_HOST}` could be one of the `ServerAlias`es or something else, if there are wildcards involved or if this is the default virtual host of this `IP:port`. (Details in [An In-Depth Discussion of Virtual Host Matching](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html).)

Comment: O_O I never come to this: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html been search for that like forever! Thanks a lot! Will go through that page and can I ask you if I have more question?

Comment: That's the best article around the subject, and may answer many of the questions you have asked in the previous two weeks.